# Composite queue in ActiveMQ in front of a topic

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I use ActiveMQ's composite queue in front of physical queues because of the ability to set permissions differently on the producer and consumer side. And this works like designed.

I also I want to use a composite queue in front of topics. In this way I can use the same permission mechanism like with the above mentioned queuing concept.

Is there a disadvantage for using composite queue in front of a topic regarding for example a potential decrease of performance? Are there other disadvantages which I have to take into account when working constructs like composite queue -> topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance impact would be negligible for most workloads. Workloads short of 100's of client connections and 100M's of messages per day is usually a blip for modern hardware and ActiveMQ.

This sounds like a policy along the lines of an 'alias naming' for destinations. This pattern exists in other products, and is definitely a valid use case for Composite Destinations in ActiveMQ-- you are well within the lines of intended use for that feature.

Disadvantage wise-- nothing jumps out you should be good.